# How do you specify object locations in function argument javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to update an Object or several Objects using a function specifying the location of what I would want to update in the Obeject. I am not sure what the correct syntax for it. My attempt below actually creates a new parameter in the original object, as instead I would like to update the existing field of the User object.

```
var User = {
    local: {
    location: {
      city: "",
      state: ""
    }
  }
}

var Profile = {
    location: {
    city: "",
    state: ""
    }
}

function update(model, parameter, updatedLocation)  {
        return model[updatedLocation] = {
        city: updatedLocation.city,
      state: updatedLocation.state,
    };
}

update(User, ["local"]["location"], { city: "ny", state: "ny"});
update(Profile, ["location"], { city: "ny", state: "ny"});

console.log(User);
console.log(Profile);
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1vxg3rx/2/)

Comment: The reason your current code is adding a new field is the way you're passing the "parameter". You want a string (not an array), and you can't combine two indexes the way you have. For instance `update(User["local"], "location", ...` and `update(Profile, "location", ...`. Also your function should read `model[parameter]`, not `model[updatedLocation]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give this a try. Basically, it's a generic way to go to any level in an object and update properties. Details in the code comments

```js
var User = {
  local: {
    location: {
      city: "",
      state: ""
    }
  }
}

var Profile = {
  location: {
    city: "",
    state: ""
  }
}

function update(obj, path, updatedProps) {
  var objToUpdate = obj;
  // Iterate down the path to find the required object
  for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    if (objToUpdate[path[i]]) {
      objToUpdate = objToUpdate[path[i]]
    } else {
      // If any path is not found, then no point continuing
      objToUpdate = null;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (objToUpdate) {
    var props = Object.keys(updatedProps);
    for (var j = 0; j < props.length; j++) {
      var prop = props[j];
      objToUpdate[prop] = updatedProps[prop] || objToUpdate[prop];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

update(User, ["local", "location"], {
  city: "ny",
  state: "ny"
});
update(Profile, ["location"], {
  city: "ny",
  state: "ny"
});

console.log("User:", User);
console.log("Profile:", Profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer here, but it doesn't require explicit coding of the `location` structure:

```js
function update(model, parameter, newVal) {
    model[parameter] = newVal;
}

update(User["local"], "location", { city: "ny", state: "ny"});
update(Profile, "location", { city: "ny", state: "ny"});
```

Or if you're only updating location, you could simplify the function:

```js
function updateLocation(model, newVal) {
    model.location = newVal;
}
```